# Tensors constructed using KroneckerDelta's - and/or displaying KroneckerDelta as a matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement, tensors

I am doing some work in elasticity and as a result am working with tensors. In particular, I would like to calculate the contraction of a fourth order tensor (the stiffness tensor) with a second order tensor (the velocity gradient) to get another tensor (the time derivative of the stress, for anyone interested).

For my material, the stiffness tensor is easily written down in terms of products of Kronecker Delta Functions such as $\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl}$. I can then easily compute the contraction by manually entering the second order tensor of interest, and using `Sum` in combination with `Part` to extract the result.

The problem is that, naturally, Mathematica displays the output in terms of `KroneckerDelta[3, i]`, for example, and there's a lot of them - it's essentially writing the matrix out elementwise using delta functions. Is there a way I can easily view this as a matrix, or map them to a matrix, or alternatively, approach this problem from a different perspective which would avoid this issue altogether? I am trying to apply something along the lines of the following to my expression:

`Replace[KroneckerDelta[i, j], KroneckerDelta[i, j] ->
TensorProduct[Part[IdentityMatrix[3], i], Part[IdentityMatrix[3], j]]]`

If this were valid Mathematica code, it would work in theory, but I get the error `The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.` along with the same for `j`.

Comment: The tensors you speak of do not have definite dimensions?

Comment: They do, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you have definite tensors like `SparseArray[{k_, k_, k_} -> 1, {3, 3, 3}]` or are you just manipulating *symbolic* tensors?

Comment: I'm not sure I know the difference. I have the definite tensors analytically, but I have input the tensors basically as a function defined using `KroneckerDelta` as, for example, `stiff[i_, j_, k_, l_] = 
 L KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[k, 
    l] + \[Mu] (KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] + 
     KroneckerDelta[i, l] KroneckerDelta[j, k])`

Comment: That definition is just a general rule for an element of your tensor. In that case, you have a $p\times q\times r\times s$ tensor whose general element is determined by `stiff`, but you do not have definite values of $p,q,r,s$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @J.M. yes, true. $p = q = r = s = 3$ is this case. Is there a better way for me to input the tensor, then?

Comment: You could use `SparseArray[]`, like I did, for a sparse tensor with definite dimensions.

Comment: But then I have to enter in all of the elements manually, which defeats the purpose of the convenience of the delta function notation.

Comment: Try `SparseArray[{{i_, j_, k_, l_} :> L KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[k, l] + μ (KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] + KroneckerDelta[i, l] KroneckerDelta[j, k])}, {3, 3, 3, 3}]`. Consider reading the docs for `SparseArray[]` and `SymmetrizedArray[]` too, while you're at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood from your answers to comments you like `KronekerDelta` in the stiffness tensor, but not in the stress tensor. You can do as follows:

```
stiff[i_, j_, k_, l_] := 
 L KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[k, 
    l] + \[Mu] (KroneckerDelta[i, k] KroneckerDelta[j, l] + 
     KroneckerDelta[i, l] KroneckerDelta[j, k])
vg = Array[v, {3, 3}];
vg // MatrixForm
stress[i_, j_] := Sum[stiff[i, j, k, l] vg[[k, l]], {k, 3}, {l, 3}]
stressT = Table[stress[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // Simplify;
stressT // MatrixForm
```

leading to

$\begin{pmatrix}
 v(1,1) & v(1,2) & v(1,3) \\
 v(2,1) & v(2,2) & v(2,3) \\
 v(3,1) & v(3,2) & v(3,3) \\
\end{pmatrix}$

and

$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}
 2 \mu  v(1,1)+L (v(1,1)+v(2,2)+v(3,3)) & \mu  (v(1,2)+v(2,1)) & \mu  (v(1,3)+v(3,1)) \\
 \mu  (v(1,2)+v(2,1)) & 2 \mu  v(2,2)+L (v(1,1)+v(2,2)+v(3,3)) & \mu  (v(2,3)+v(3,2)) \\
 \mu  (v(1,3)+v(3,1)) & \mu  (v(2,3)+v(3,2)) & 2 \mu  v(3,3)+L (v(1,1)+v(2,2)+v(3,3)) \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: @J.M. thanks for editing that long equation

Comment: No worries; it certainly was starting to look garbled at the right...

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. v, {i, j} = v, {j, i}, how can we modify this boundary conditions?